# Is there a reason I am unable to activate my virtualenv without navigating to the Scripts folder first?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've been using a venv for a month now as I learn django, but the last couple of days I am unable to activate it with the typical `python venv\Scripts\activate` line. When I type that into my cmd prompt, I am given the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\blog-proj>python ll_env/Scripts/activate
  File "ll_env/Scripts/activate", line 4
    deactivate () {
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This seems to imply that there is an issue with the activate file, but I have not opened/ edited it before (just to be sure it wasn't the activate file, I opened it after I got the error and there is a closing curly brace) and when I navigate to `blog-proj\ll_env\Scripts` and type `activate`, the venv starts up just the same.

Is there any reason why it's starting to do this now and any way to fix it? It's not the biggest problem in the world, but it is a bit annoying having to change directories all the time to activate it.

Comment: `activate` is not a Python script.

Comment: In windows you need to call the `activate.bat` script

Comment: Thanks guys. I've been doing so much with django that I've been prefacing everything with ```python```. I appreciate the responses

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, `activate` is not a Python script. It's a batch or bash file, depending on whether you're using Windows or Linux respectively.

You should run it directly, instead. In Windows, assuming your current working directory is the project folder, containing the virtual environment folder, and your virtual environment is named `venv`, this would be the correct command:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

As an aside, you should always check that your own methods and assumptions are correct before concluding that an external library is in error.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I never said I thought an external library was wrong

Comment: With all due respect:
"This seems to imply that there is an issue with the activate file"

Comment: Which was immediately followed up by an explanation of why it couldn't be something wrong with the activate file